# How does a gramophone work?

Tags: waves, acoustics

A gramophone needle moves on a groove with a radius. How do you relate the length of the groove and the speed of the rotating gramophone plate with the frequency of the sound it produces?

Answer (score 2):

The sound corresponds to wiggles in the groove. We call each wiggle – in which the groove goes (let's say) from its mid or usual place, to the left, back to mid, then to right and back to mid – one cycle. Suppose that this cycle occupies a distance $\lambda$ measured along the circumference of the groove. If the record (or disc or disk) is rotating at $n$ turns per unit time then the speed at which a groove of radius $r$ is moving past the pick-up needle is $2 \pi r\ n$. So the number of cycles per second, that is the frequency, is
$$f=\frac{2 \pi r\ n} {\lambda}$$
**Example:** Suppose that the record is turning at 33 revolutions per minute. Then $n=33/60=0.55\ \text s^{-1}$. Suppose that  the track radius is 0.050 m (that's about 2 inches) and $\lambda$ is 0.20 mm = $2.0 \times 10^{-4}$ m. This gives $f$ = 864 Hz.

**Note:** You'll have spotted that to get the same frequency, $f$ of sound from a groove near the outside of the record (large $r$) than that from an inner groove (smaller $r$) will require a larger $\lambda$. This may sound complicated, but in fact it comes about automatically when the soft master (or pre-master) disc is rotated under a needle made to vibrate by an amplified signal from the microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are recording the sound with a similar set-up, it works on its own.

While recording you are spinning the disc with a constant speed, thus the distance covered by a point on the rim is longer than that of one at the middle. So a recording of any sound takes more space on the rim. But the needle moves through the grooves faster on the rim as well. If the distance at the rim is twice the distance at the middle so does the speed. So it takes the needle the same amount of time to cover whether its on the rim or the middle, and everything balances out in the end.